# Models evaluation and parameter tuning with CV

Tags: scikit-learn, model, evaluation

I try to compare three models `SVM` `RandomForest` and `LogisticRegression`.
I have an imbalance dataset. First i split it to with a 80% - 20% ratio to train and test set. I set the `stratify=y`.
Next, i used StratifiedKfold only on train set. What i try to do now is fit the models and choose the best one. Also i want to use grid search for each one of the models to find the best parameters.
My code until now is the next

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, stratify=y, random_state=42)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=21)


for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    X_train_folds, X_test_folds = X_train[train_index], X_train[test_index]
    y_train_folds, y_test_folds = y_train[train_index], y_train[test_index]

X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2 = X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

How can i fit a model usin all the folds? How can i gridsearch? Should i have a doulbe loop? can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn's [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

You will find an example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_stats.html) of how to evaluate the performance of the various models and assess the statistical significance of the results.